# Plotting each row of a csv file contigously using Python

Tags: python, csv, numpy, matplotlib, multidimensional-array

I have a CSV files organized like this:

```
1, 2, 3, 4
5, 6, 7, 8
9, 10, 11, 12
```

Using numpy I stored the file using **genfromtxt** in a variable **x**. So each row of x is a row of the CSV file, and x is an ndarray object.

I want to plot the data so its like:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12
```

---

To clarify the data is currently plotting like (0,1) and (0,5), since each row is a new array the index resets at the start of each new row.

I would like to plot it so the points are (0, 1) and (4, 5) instead,

---

My attempt was to append or concatenate rows in a for loop, but it seems like ndarray types don't have those methods.

Thank you for reading!

Comment: Why not just remove all `\n` characters from the file?

Comment: Have you tried reshaping the array?  With `reshape` or `ravel`?  This appears to be a basic array manipulation task.  The fact that the array comes from a file is incidental.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `csv` module and a double list comprehension you can build a numpy array very simply:

```
with open("input.csv") as f:
    cr = csv.reader(f)
    vector = np.array([int(x) for row in cr for x in row])
```

let's print `vector`:

```
[ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12]
```

Comment: Thank you! That combined the rows perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Simulating a csv file with a list of lines:

```
In [1]: txt=b"""1, 2, 3, 4
   ...: 5, 6, 7, 8
   ...: 9, 10, 11, 12"""
In [2]: txt = txt.splitlines()
In [3]: txt
Out[3]: [b'1, 2, 3, 4', b'5, 6, 7, 8', b'9, 10, 11, 12']
```

Loaded with `genfromtxt` I get a 2d array

```
In [4]: x = np.genfromtxt(txt, delimiter=',', dtype=int)
In [5]: x
Out[5]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])
In [6]: x.shape
Out[6]: (3, 4)
```

Such an array can be easily reshaped into a `flat` 1d array:

```
In [7]: x1 = x.ravel()
In [8]: x1
Out[8]: array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12])
In [9]: x.reshape(12)
Out[9]: array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12])
```

The reverse is just as easy:

Create a 1d array with the same values, and reshape it to a (3,4) array (or a (4,3) or (2,6) etc):

```
In [10]: y = np.arange(1,13)
In [11]: y
Out[11]: array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12])
In [12]: y.reshape(3,4)
Out[12]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])
```